# Trying to find out what is wrong with my methodology for this Laplace Transform Example.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am just starting to learn convolutions and Laplace Transforms and am doing an example in my book and I don't understand why my methodology is incorrect so I will give the book's methodology first and then my methodology and I would appreciate if someone can tell me where I am misunderstanding something.

Find the PS to the following IDE:

$x'(t)+2x(t)-4\int_0^te^{(t-\tau)}x(\tau)d\tau = e^t$

where $x(0) = 0$

Book's Methodology:

let X(s) = $\scr{L}(x(t))$

Apply LaPlace Transform to both sides of the equation to get

$(sX(s)-x(0))+2X(s)-4\scr{L}(e^t\circledast x(t))=\scr{L}(e^t)$

We Know $ \scr{L}(e^t\circledast x(t)) = \scr{L}(e^t)\scr{L}(x(t))$

So let's also apply the IC's and rewrite the equation as

$sX(s)+2X(s)-4\cfrac{1}{s-1}X(s)=\scr{L}(e^t)$

Solving for X(s) and performing partial fraction, we obtain

$X(s) = \cfrac{1}{5}(\cfrac{1}{s-2}+\cfrac{4}{s+3})\scr{L}(e^t) $

Then applying inverse LT, we get

$x(t) = \cfrac{1}{5}\scr{L}^{-1}((\cfrac{1}{s-2}+\cfrac{4}{s+3})\scr{L}(e^t)) = \cfrac{1}{5}(e^{2t}+4e^{-3t}) \circledast e^t$

Using $e^{\alpha t} \circledast e^{\beta t} =\cfrac{e^{\alpha t}-e^{\beta t}}{\alpha - \beta}$

we get

$x(t) = \cfrac{1}{5}(\cfrac{e^{2t}-e^{t}}{2 - 1} + 4\cfrac{e^{-3t}-e^{t}}{-3 - 1}) = \cfrac{1}{20}(-3e^t+4e^{2t}-e^{-3t})$

Now What is wrong with my methodology?

My Methodology:

Apply LaPlace Transform to both sides of the equation to get

$(sX(s)-x(0))+2X(s)-4\scr{L}(e^t\circledast x(t))=\scr{L}(e^t)$

We Know $ \scr{L}(e^t\circledast x(t)) = \scr{L}(e^t)\scr{L}(x(t))$

So let's also apply the IC's and rewrite the equation as

$sX(s)+2X(s)-4\cfrac{1}{s-1}X(s)=\cfrac{1}{s-1}$ (Here I use $\cfrac {1}{s-1}$ instead on the RHS but I don't think there should be an issue here? Am I mistaken?)

$X(s)(\cfrac{s^2+s-6}{s-1}) = \cfrac{1}{s-1}$

$X(s) = \cfrac{(s-1)}{(s-1)(s^2+s-6)} = \cfrac{1}{(s^2+s-6)} = \cfrac{1}{5}(\cfrac{1}{s-2}) -\cfrac{1}{5}(\cfrac{1}{s+3})$ (I used partial fraction decomposition)

Now apply inverse laplace Transform

$x(t) = \cfrac{1}{5}\scr{L}^{-1}(\cfrac{1}{s-2})-\cfrac{1}{5}\scr{L}^{-1}(\cfrac{1}{s+3}) = \cfrac{1}{5}(e^{2t}-e^{-3t})$ which does not match the book's answer
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for any help

Comment: BTW I noticed some errors as well and sort of autocorrrected some of them so the book page has even more errors then what I listed but I just wanted to double check if the book's solution was right or not (Basically you'll see that the page is ripe with errors)

Comment: It happens sometimes yes to find errors in some textbooks. But your solution is prefectly fine. i checked both solutions.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just wish to confirm a hunch I have. Both methodologies (Method 1 (Book method): Using Convolutions, Method 2 (My method): Using Partial Fraction Decomposition) are both perfectly fine ways to solve a problem like this correct? Generally The Convolution method written in the book should be used if taking the partial fraction decomposition is difficult correct?

Comment: Yeah both methods are correct and give same result. Sometimes fraction decomposition as your solution is better and sometimes using convolution is easier. It depends on the differential equation.

Comment: Exactly Thank YOu

Comment: You're welcome. Flash...+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They made a mistake in the book after this line:
$$x(t) = \cfrac{1}{5}\left(\cfrac{e^{2t}-e^{t}}{2 - 1} + 4\cfrac{e^{-3t}-e^{t}}{-3 - 1} \right) $$
It should give:
$$x(t) = \cfrac{1}{5}({e^{2t}\color{red}{-e^{t}}} -{e^{-3t} \color{red}{+e^{t}}})$$
This gives the same answer as yours:
$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{5}\left(e^{2t} -e^{-3t}\right)$$